# Changing width and height of svg file

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animate

I was given a link to the animated blobby button  in codepen and I am supposed to change the text and the font-size of the text inside it. I have tried applying width and height to the HTML svg tag, but it's not working. Also, when I copied the button with changed text and put it somewhere else and changed the text again, it did not change. I cannot figure this out. Please help

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:900");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519501025264-65ba15a82390?w=1600);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: Raleway, serif;
  &:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
}

svg {
  width: 80vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  max-width: 430px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  path {
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: blob 2s infinite forwards;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    &:hover {
      fill: #fafafa;
    }
  }
  text {
    font-size: 45px;
  }
}

@keyframes blob {
  25% {
    d: path( "M 90 210 C 90 180 110 160 130 160 C 160 160 180 140 200 130 C 230 120 270 100 290 140 C 310 170 340 100 360 140 C 370 160 390 180 390 210 C 390 240 380 290 350 280 C 330 270 300 280 280 290 C 260 300 230 300 220 290 C 200 270 160 310 140 280 C 130 260 90 240 90 210 ");
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  50% {
    d: path( "M 90 210 C 90 180 100 150 120 130 C 150 100 180 140 200 130 C 230 120 270 100 290 140 C 300 160 330 130 360 140 C 390 150 390 180 390 210 C 390 240 380 300 350 280 C 330 270 320 230 280 260 C 260 280 220 310 200 290 C 180 270 160 280 140 280 C 110 280 90 240 90 210");
  }
  75% {
    d: path( "M 90 210 C 90 180 110 180 130 170 C 150 160 170 130 200 130 C 240 130 260 150 290 140 C 310 130 340 120 360 140 C 380 160 390 180 390 210 C 390 240 380 260 350 270 C 320 280 290 270 270 260 C 240 250 230 280 210 290 C 180 310 130 300 110 280 C 90 260 90 240 90 210");
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <svg viewBox="45 60 400 320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill="#fff" d="M 90 210 C 90 180 90 150 90 150 C 150 150 180 150 180 150 C 180 150 300 150 300 150 C 300 150 330 150 390 150 C 390 150 390 180 390 210 C 390 240 390 270 390 270 C 330 270 300 270 300 270 C 300 270 180 270 180 270 C 180 270 150 270 90 270 C 90 270 90 240 90 210" mask="url(#knockout-text)" />
    <mask id="knockout-text">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" x="0" y="0" />
      <text x="147" y="227" fill="#000">BUTTON</text>
   </mask>
  </svg>
<!--- M 90 210 C 90 180 90 150 150 150 C 150 150 180 150 180 150 C 180 150 300 150 300 150 C 300 150 330 150 330 150 C 390 150 390 180 390 210 C 390 240 390 270 330 270 C 330 270 300 270 300 270 C 300 270 180 270 180 270 C 180 270 150 270 150 270 C 90 270 90 240 90 210 --->
</html>
```

Comment: You may need to change the viewBox attribute of the svg element. Please rad about the  [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)

Comment: @enxaneta hello, thank you for answering. I tried changing the width and height with viewBox but it is changing with the text inside, and I need the text to stay in its place. can you help please

Answer (score 0):

The CSS declaration for the text element is nested under the SVG declaration. Un-nest it and it will work. Aka this works fine:

```
svg {
  width: 80vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  max-width: 430px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  path {
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: blob 2s infinite forwards;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    &:hover {
      fill: #fafafa;
    }
  }
}

text {
    font-size: 45px;
 }
```